# Shell initialization files

Tags: linux, shell, csh

Is it possible to track what files were invoked from what directories? (.login .profile, .cshrc)?

The reason I'm asking is because I've deleted all init files from my home directory, but the shell still starts and even sets some of my custom variables (perhaps using some cached files from somewhere?), and I'm wondering where those files are?

I'm running under Red Hat 6.8

Comment: How do you start your shell? If you just start one from a previous shell, it will inherit the variables.

Comment: If you don't have init files in your home directory, it uses the ones in `/etc`

Answer (score 3):

To trace wich files are opened :

```
strace -f -e trace=file -o /tmp/trace /bin/bash
cat /tmp/trace
```

Feel free to replace `bash` with your shell flavor